# server send events with spring mvc always closed

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, server-sent-events

I have do a sse  demo,but it not work, i post the js and java code,please tell me what's the wrong,thank you.

this is the js:

```
if (window.EventSource) {
    var source = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8080/pushweb/push');
    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log(e.data, this.readyState);
    },false);

    source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        console.log("conncted",this.readyState);
    },false);
    source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            console.log("closed");
        } else if(e.target.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING){
            console.log("connecting");
        }else {
            console.log("error"+this.readyState);
        }
    }, false);
} else {
    console.log("not support SSE");
}
```

this is the springmvc code:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@Controller
public class PushController
{
@RequestMapping(value = "/push", produces = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String push()
{
    String str =Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return "data:"+str + "\n\n\n";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/message")
@ResponseBody
public String message()
{
    String stre = "hello";
    return stre;
}
```

}

[this is the chrome console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CXMh.png)

Comment: If you want debugging help, at least provide the expected and the onserved behavior, "tell me what's wrong" is not sufficient. Please also read [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you need to use SseEmitter to send events. See [Server-Sent Events with Spring](https://golb.hplar.ch/p/Server-Sent-Events-with-Spring) (blog).